# Cloning bitmap free count err on proxmox drive

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla, proxmox

I have a small business server (custome build) that runs proxmox for virtualizing common office services (samba, AD, web server, etc).

I use clonezilla for all my cloning purposes and have never encountered this problem before. Clonezilla will not clone my main system/boot drive for the proxmox server. The drive is an 120GB mSATA connected to the mother board.

This is the error I get:

> bitmap free count err, free: 6871416 Partclone fial, please check
>   /var/log/partclone.log

inside /var/log/partclone.log:

```
...
Reading Super Block
Calculating bitmap...
extfclone.c: bitmap free count err, free: 15583233
```

I'm wondering if it could have anything to do with the boot partition showing up as locked on GParted? or that I'm using LVM on the drive?

This is what this drive looks like in GParted:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the advice of [this forum post](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/forums/forum/394751/topic/3523049) I was able to fix the problem by entering advanced or expert mode in clonezilla and checking the **"-fsck-src-part"** option.

I suppose this fixes drive inconsistencies and was able to clone the drive.

Comment: thanks, this did the trick for me too cloning an 80gb toshiba drive with ubuntu to a 160gb seagate